# unable to create autogenerated mysql

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, workbench

I am prototyping a MySQL/Java/Eclipselink (so far) solution and the MySQL workbench is throwing an error as I try to alter a column to make it autogenerated:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `characters`.`stats` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS () ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: 
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `characters`.`stats` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ()
```

While I could drop and recreate the table it seems like this change should be accommodated by the workbench; is "id" a reserved word in MySQL?  The field is defined as an "int" and not null.

Second, my goal for this is to have a List in Entity1 (where the entities are instances of classes); is there a way of doing this without an artificial id field?  I was having difficulty using a foreign key of two fields (that uniquely identify each record).

Comment: about to - thanks!

Comment: Yes and no.  It can autogenerate but I realized I wanted autoincrement.  Then a colleague of mine pointed out that I was actually using the field wrong - you can't have an autoincrement field as a key field in MySql even though it is unique!